# Overstayed 2 years in the Philippines but want to stay here permanently

Tags: us-citizens, overstay, philippines

I'm a US citizen who moved here 2 years ago when I was 18 to be with my girlfriend. My visa has long expired because I never had the funds to pay for the extension fees when I needed to.

Now, I have a job online but it's still not enough to pay for the big amount for overstaying for over 2 years here, but I can save up for it in just a few months, but my longterm plan is to marry my Filipina girlfriend I came here for and live here permanently, but also be able to travel within the country and maybe in the future, outside as well (so I can take her to meet my family in the US). Is there a way to fix my visa issues but still be able to live here in the Philippines at this point?

Comment: Sounds like you're going to need more money than you have right now, so that you can pay for a lawyer and for visa fees. Can you increase your earnings, or borrow from family?

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, while it does not seem like a big deal to overstay a visa, most countries see it as a very serious crime, and people who do it are treated very harshly.

According to [this site](https://liveinthephilippines.com/content/what-happens-if-you-overstay-your-visa/), it sounds like you have to get together enough money to pay the overstay fees before you present yourself at an airport. You must also have money to cover the visa extension fees you would have paid if you had stayed lawfully.

When you do go to the airport, they will definitely catch you (they know when you were supposed to leave - it's in your passport) and demand that you pay the overstay fees, then they will blacklist you from ever entering the Philippines again, and you will have to leave immediately.

If you are caught on overstay (either at the airport or anywhere else) and don't have enough money to cover the overstay fees, you will be sent to jail until you can raise the money. For this reason, be very careful who you talk to about your situation - someone could report you and get you sent to jail, if they decided they didn't like you.

As mentioned above, once you have left the Philippines, you will never be able to enter again. Legally, there is nothing you can do about that, since you overstayed your visa by more than a year, and the penalty for that is to be blacklisted for life. Many other countries have similarly harsh penalties for this, so it is not unique to the Philippines.